# xdotool how to send Ctrl + mouse wheel up to a program?

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, xdotool

In the text editor SciTE, you have to use Ctrl + Mouse Wheel up/down to temporarily change the font size; however, my mouse wheel is broken, so I thought of sending this command through a terminal command, that is, using `xdotool`.

I use this to find the SciTE window ID:

```
$ echo $(wcalc -q --ints $(wmctrl -l | grep SciTE | awk '{print $1}'))
6291463
```

Then, I've tried this:

```
xdotool windowactivate 6291463 && xdotool keydown ctrl click 5 keyup ctrl
```

This focuses the right window, but there are no changes in font size (with either `click 4` or `click 5`.

I've also tried this:

```
xdotool keydown --window 6291463 ctrl click --window 6291463 5 keyup --window 6291463 ctrl
```

Command executes without any errors printed, but again, no change in font size.

What would be the right `xdotool` invocation, so I can send an emulation of Ctrl+Mouse Wheel Up to a program like Scite?

Comment: Does SciTE support Ctrl+Plus and Ctrl+Minus?

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea - indeed it does! That fixes my immediate problem, but it'd be still cool to know how to make `xdotool` do that...

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem with you.

`xdotool keydown ctrl click 5 keyup ctrl` seems only to scroll down. So I tweaked the command a little bit to delay the releasing of ctrl.

Now `xdotool keydown ctrl click 5 && xdotool keyup ctrl` works for me